# Present of uninitialized color attachment issue

Tags: ios, opengl-es

When I run my OpenGL app, I get the following error:

[image]

I googled but can't get any useful information.

Here're a piece of source code:

```
- (void)render:(CADisplayLink*)displayLink {
    [self.canvas clear];
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    NSInteger mLength = mParticles.count;
    NSInteger drawCount = 0;
    NSInteger drawIndex = 0;
    WQParticle* drawParticle;
    CGFloat drawX,drawY,drawScale,drawAngle;
    GLKMatrix4 changeColorMatrix;
    if (mLength > 0){
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);
        glViewport(0,0,width,height);
        drawCount = 0;
        drawIndex = -1;
        while ( drawCount < mLength){
            drawParticle = mParticles[drawCount];

            if(!(drawParticle.flg && random > 0.5)){

                if (drawIndex != drawParticle.texIndex) {
                    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
                    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, (GLuint)(texture[drawParticle.texIndex]));
                    glUniform1i((GLint)uniLocation[1], 0);
                    drawIndex = drawParticle.texIndex;
                }

                if(drawParticle.flg){
                    drawX = drawParticle.posX + (random * 1 - 0.5) * drawParticle.scale * 0.06;
                    drawY = drawParticle.posY + (random * 1 - 0.5) * drawParticle.scale * 0.06;
                    drawScale = drawParticle.scale * (random * 0.4 + 0.8);
                    changeColorMatrix = [self setChangeColorWithDp:drawParticle n:random];
                    drawX = drawX / drawScale;
                    drawY = drawY / drawScale;
                }else{
                    drawX = drawParticle.posX / drawParticle.scale;
                    drawY = drawParticle.posY / drawParticle.scale;
                    drawScale = drawParticle.scale;
                    changeColorMatrix = [self setChangeColorWithDp:drawParticle n:1];
                }
                glUniformMatrix4fv((GLint)uniLocation[2], 1, 0, changeColorMatrix.m);
                drawAngle = drawParticle.angle;
                CGFloat drawR = sqrt(drawX * drawX + drawY * drawY);
                CGFloat oa = 2 * M_PI - acos(drawX / drawR);
                drawX = cos(oa - drawAngle) * drawR;
                drawY = sin(oa - drawAngle) * drawR;

                mMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;
                mMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(mMatrix, drawAngle, 0, 0, 1);
                mMatrix = GLKMatrix4Scale(mMatrix, drawScale, drawScale, drawScale);
                mMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(mMatrix, drawX, drawY, 0);
                mvpMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(f_tmpMatrix, mMatrix);

                glUniform1i((GLint)uniLocation[3], YES);
                glUniformMatrix4fv((GLint)uniLocation[0], 1, 0, mvpMatrix.m);
                glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
            }

            if (drawParticle.life > 0) {
                [mVF getForceFromPosWithPx:drawParticle.posX Py:drawParticle.posY];
                [drawParticle setVFupdateWithOutX:mVF.outX OutY:mVF.outY];
                drawCount++;
                continue;
            }
            [mParticles removeObjectAtIndex:drawCount];
            mLength = mLength - 1;
        }
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);
    }

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FBOTexture);
    mMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;
    mvpMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(tmpMatrix, mMatrix);
    glUniformMatrix4fv((GLint)uniLocation[0], 1, 0, mvpMatrix.m);
    glUniform1i((GLint)uniLocation[3], NO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    [self.canvas.glContext presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to clear the framebuffer before you start rendering, like the error suggests? Put a `glClear()` at the start of your render method, and you should be all set.

Comment: @RetoKoradi `[self.canvas clear];` already contains methods `glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);glClearDepthf(1.0);`

Comment: Other guess is that your viewport or scissor box is not the same size as the application render surface, so you are only clearing / rendering to a subset of the window surface.

Comment: @Isogen74 EXACTLY! I Just use a part of window area for rendering. I'm new to OpenGL, how can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: @Allen Added as an answer, as it seems like probable cause.

Answer (score 2):

Check that glViewport() is set the size of the renderpass you are rendering to, and that either glScissor() is set to that size too, or that scissor test is disabled via glDisable().